# selecting a month in html site and read only the selected from mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating a program which keeps track of employers and their monthly hours. I have created database with 3 columns. First is month, second is name and third is hours. What I want to do is for user to select a month and get every employers name and hours that month. I have AJAX implemented  and only struggling with PHP. Also the second question: at the moment the table loads automatically. How can I make it to wait until selection is made and then the table should display only names and hours of the selected month?

Database looks like:

```
month name hours

1   xyx   180
3   xxx   180
2   yyy   174
1   yxy   160
```

HTML:

```
Mesec: <select name="mesec">
<option value="1">Januar</option>
<option value="2">Februar</option>
<option value="3">Marec</option>
</select><br><br>

<title>smart</title>
<scriptsrc="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
setInterval(function() {
$('#results').load('tabela.php');
}, 3000);
});
// ]]></script>
<div id="results">Loading data ...</div>
```

What I would need is some help with PHP side, where I am really not good.

PHP for showing table:

```
echo "<table border='1'>

<tr>
<th>mesec</th>
<th>ime</th>
<th>stevilo_ur</th>
</tr>";

while ( $db_v = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $db_v['mesec'] ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . $db_v['ime'] ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . $db_v['stevilo_ur'] ."</td>";
echo"</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: So what is your problem with `PHP` side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"setInterval() method calls a function ... at specified intervals" so you load that table over and over again, it should be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mesec").change(function(){
        $('#results').load('tabela.php', {choice: $(this).val()});
    });
});
```

And in PHP you use that $_POST['choice'] in your sql query (which you btw didin't include). Propably something like

```
'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `month` =  ' . $_POST['choice']
```